# Linksys WiFi usb dongle and linux woes

Tags: linux, usb, wireless-networking, fedora

I have a Linksys [WUSB54GC](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/WUSB54GC) usb dongle and I have exhausted every thing I know about making this thing work in linux. I am using Fedora 13. Since it is not ready I can not view any networks. Any ideas would be great.

`lspci -v` does not list the the item.

tail of the system log

```
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 8
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=1737, idProduct=0077
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: Product: 802.11 g WLAN
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Ralink
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy3::radio
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy3::assoc
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy3::quality
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> found WiFi radio killswitch rfkill3 (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/ieee80211/phy3/rfkill3) (driver <unknown>)
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: rt2800usb 1-7:1.0: firmware: requesting rt2870.bin
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): driver supports SSID scans (scan_capa 0x01).
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'rt2800usb' ifindex: 6)
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): now managed
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: 1 -> 2 (reason 2)
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): preparing device.
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason: 2).
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state:  starting -> ready
Jun  2 20:14:35 localhost NetworkManager[1367]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: 2 -> 3 (reason 42)
```

[root@localhost log]# iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=8 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

`lsusb -v`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1737:0077 Linksys 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1737 Linksys
  idProduct          0x0077 
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 Ralink
  iProduct                2 802.11 g WLAN
  iSerial                 3 1.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           67
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              450mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           7
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              5 1.0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: Exact same error with the newest Ubuntu as well

Comment: can you also supply the lspci -v information for that device?

Comment: @James updated question. The dongle isn't listed under that.

Comment: How about lsusb -v ?

Comment: @James added the linksys part

Comment: @MrStatic the lsusb didnt give me the details i had hoped for. But a google search did. Apperently your device uses the RT257x/RT2671 chipset from Ralink. Ralink provides the linux driver source for this chipset on their site... i expect there would be compilation instructions in the download. Some guy also got Ndiswrapper to work even though it is not listed on the ndiswrapper site. See solution for details.

Comment: Recompile the kernel.

Comment: Recompile the kernel is just freaking sad. :( I plan to try the ndiswrapper route first as I have dealt with that before. Then I will try to compile the driver then we will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your driver looks like it loaded properly.

If you do a `iwlist wlan0 scan` does it come back with a list of networks in the area?

have you tried manually connecting to a wireless network with something like this?:

```
 iwconfig interface key xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

I think that only works for WEP. You probably need wpa_supplicant to connect to WPA encrypted networks.

Thats about as far as I got before I switched to Ubuntu. All the wifi devices i've used automatically work with a nice gui (network manager?). This was years ago though... maybe its fixed and all you need is wpa_supplicant or something.

Edit:

Here is the link to the guy that used Ndiswrapper:

http://jefim.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/how-to-linksys-wusb54gc-wireless-and-ubuntu-linux-704-feisty/

Here is the link to Ralink if you'd like to try to compile their driver:

http://www.ralinktech.com/support.php?s=2

Comment: scan results in nothing and I already tried to manually connect. And as stated in my comment Ubuntu did not work either. Same exact error. wpa_supplicant comes with the wireless tools now by default

Comment: Ended up doing the ndiswrapper :(

Comment: @MrStatic Glad to hear it worked! Why the frown?

Comment: Linux at this point should be able to support a large company wifi driver on its own lol

Comment: @MrStatic Very true... especially since the manufacturer supplies the source.